# Differential backup job is working but not the Full daily backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, sql-server-agent

I have a full backup job for my database that runs once daily, I see it posted daily in the folder that it should go to, but when I check the "View History" for this job in SQL Server Agent, there are red X's which tells me that it didn't run successfuly...

The opposite is happening for the Differential job that I see running successfully in the job history and posted successfully too in the destination folder.

I'm planning to restore both of these copies to see if they contain current updated data, but regardless, if I see the full `.bak` file in my folder, shouldn't the job show that it ran successfuly with a green checkmark?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64679/discussion-on-question-by-shayma-ahmad-differential-backup-job-is-working-but-no).